# box-shadow with background-clip: content-box

Tags: css

I've got a div with some padding and I'm using `background-clip: content-box` to apply a `background-color`. This works like a charm but the problem comes when I try to apply also a `box-shadow`:

[image]

Is possible to convine both properties? I'd like to do something like "box-shadow-clip: content-box" as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use drop shadow instead of box-shadow to achieve this

```
div {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for  ;)